# Как найти произведение столбца в двумерном массиве на Python

Tags: python

Предположил что делается так, но оказался не прав, вообще суть задания - найти найменьшее проивзедение столбцов.

```py
n=int(input('Введите кол-во строк матрицы: '))
matrix=[]
for i in range(n):
    matrix.append(list(map(int,input('Введите матрицу, содержащую только положительные числа:').split())))
print(matrix)
minimum=1000000000
for i in matrix:
    for j in i:
        if matrix[i][j]*matrix[i+1][j]<minimum :
            minimum=matrix[i][j]*matrix[i+1][j]
print(minimum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упрощаем, пишем функцию для поиска произведения членов списка, конкретно для данной задачи для одного столбца

```py
import math

def column_mul(matrix, number):
    """Возвращает произведение членов столбца с номером number"""
    column = [row[number] for row in matrix] # столбец с номером number
    return math.prod(column)
```

Далее используем данную функцию для количества столбцов и храним результат в переменной `mul_all_columns`, а затем используем метод `min`

```py
mul_all_columns = []
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    mul_all_columns.append(column_mul(matrix, i))

minimum = min(mul_all_columns)
```

либо можно сократить до одной строки

```py
minimum = min(column_mul(matrix, i) for i in range(len(matrix)))
```

также можно и максимум найти

```py
maximum = max(column_mul(matrix, i) for i in range(len(matrix)))
```

Comment: А как работает цикл for до len(matrix), если matrix не объявлено?

Comment: @Студент а, так вы ТС и есть:) вчера был другой ник. У вас уже есть переменная matrix я её и использую

Comment: Понял, думал код с нуля написанный. Всё получилось, спасибо! Разобрался :)

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, требуется найти столбец с минимальным произведением элементов.

Тогда внешний цикл должен быть по номеру столбца, внутри него сначала задаётся product=1, считается произведение в цикле по строкам, после чего product сравнивается с максимумом

Comment: Не совсем понял почему product будет сранвиваться с максимумом, product не меняется ведь, а максимум это будет что? И произведение как правильно писать не знаю\

Comment: В цикле `product *=matrix [i][j]; `

Comment: С [j] проблема, в формате list , а должен быть целым , если написать int тогда выходим за предел list index out of range

Comment: Логика элементарная, я практически все описал. Постарайтесь вникнуть, без этого программы писать не получится.